# Cocoa's PDFKit : disable "print to pdf" options

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, printing

I am using Coco'a PDFKit (Quartz) to show a PDF viewer. Is it possible to enable printing it solely to a printer, and not to a file?

I currently perform:

```
[self.pdfView printWithInfo:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] autoRotate:YES];
```

(while self.pdfView is of type "PDFView" from Quartz's framework)

What should I do in order to remove the entire "PDF" drop-down menu from the printing menu?
[image: PDF drop down menu - how can I remove it?]

Answer (score 1):

I know its old thread, but to restrict some options you can set the NSPrintProtected key in printInfo dictionary.

```
[[printInfo dictionary] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"NSPrintProtected"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to suppress the PDF drop down menu you won't probably get around without subclassing `NSPrintPanel`. `NSPrintPanel` offers `- setAccessoryView` method to add functionality, but to my knowledge there is no built-in way to withdraw functionality from it.

Alternatively, you could suppress the whole print panel by calling `- setShowsPrintPanel:` on your `NSPrintOperation` object. Of course this has the drawback that the user cannot select the options the print panel would be offering normally.

Comment: I see setAccessoryView is deprecated, is it possible to do the same with removeAccessoryController? Do you have some online example I can view?

Comment: No, removeAccessoryController can only remove accessory controllers that you added before. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printpanel/osxp_printpanel.html for all the details.